# Watching image AI in action while generating an image

Tags: image-generation, dall-e

I am looking for a video that shows how an image gen AI creates an image - i.e. all (or many of) the intermediate steps. Chatbots show how they generate an answer: word by word (or token by token) and I can watch it generating. Image AIs like Dall-E just present the result - but under the hood they generate the image step by step, "image token" by "image token" (whatever this is). I assume that this is the case because they are based on the transformer architecture and transformers give their answers "token" by "token".

Has anybody seen a transformer-based image AI "in action" - not just the results?

Comment: This is (probably) not applicable to Dall-E but if you are using the [Stable Diffusion web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) you can use this [extension](https://github.com/vladmandic/sd-extension-steps-animation) to visualize the intermediary steps.

Comment: @Turamarth: Thanks, but this goes far beyond my abilitities. Do you know of any public videos that would demonstrate it? Did you create some and can share them?

Comment: I don't have a video at hand but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion#/media/File:X-Y_plot_of_algorithmically-generated_AI_art_of_European-style_castle_in_Japan_demonstrating_DDIM_diffusion_steps.png) has a figure that shows how the image looks after different numbers of steps.

Comment: @Turamarth: Thanks a lot, you saved my day, that's all I wanted to see! Do you "understand" step 20? How can it be that Stable Diffusion first creates a bigger castle and removes the tower, just to make it smaller again and add almost the same tower again? Can this be "groked"?

Comment: Stable diffusion allows the usage of different samplers. The image I linked uses the DDIM sampler, which injects random noise during its sampling steps. This might explain those variations in the process. I just found [this](https://stable-diffusion-art.com/samplers/) page about samplers, which I highly recommend. Beside having actual videos of the sampling process it also shows and explains some of the differences between the samplers.